# How can I compare two IEnumerable<> objects and return a new one?

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, ienumerable

I want to compare two `IEnumerable<>` object and return a new `IEnumerable<>` object.

Below is my code where I have `newFiles` object and then I have `OriginalFiles` object. I want to compare these two `IEnumerable<>` object and find those files which are new files and also got modified files.

`FileConfig` class has `md5Hash` value of each file as a string so I can compare `OriginalFiles` and `newFiles` object on `md5Hash` string to figure out what files have changed and then create a new `IEnumerable<FileConfig>` object with those modified files + new files.

**For example:** if `newFiles` object has total 10 files and `OriginalFiles` has 8 files so that means there are two new files in it. And then remaining 8 I will compare and see what files are changed by using `md5Hash` string so if 5 files changed out of 8 and there were two new files also so total I will return 7 files as `IEnumerable<FileConfig>` object.

```
public class ProcessFile
{
    public IEnumerable<FileConfig> OriginalFiles { get; set; }


    public IEnumerable<FileConfig> GetNewFiles(IEnumerable<FileConfig> newFiles)
    {
        // compare OriginalFiles and newFiles object and return a new IEnumerable<FileConfig> object 
        // which has only those files which are modified or new by comparing on md5Hash string
       foreach (var element1 in newFiles)
        {
            var newFileName = element1.Name;
            var newMd5Hash = element1.MD5Hash;
            foreach (var element2 in this.OriginalFiles)
            {
                var originalFileName = element2.Name;
                var originalmd5Hash = element2.MD5Hash;
                if (newFileName.Equals(originalFileName, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) && !newMd5Hash.Equals(originalmd5Hash, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
                {
                    yield return new FileConfig
                    {
                        Name = newFileName,
                        Timestamp = element1.Timestamp,
                        MD5Hash = newMd5Hash
                    };
                }
            }
        }

    }
}

public class FileConfig
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime Timestamp { get; set; }
    public string MD5Hash { get; set; }
}
```

I can run two for loops and compare each file on their `md5Hash` string and figure out what files have been modified and return new `IEnumerable<FileConfig>` object but is there any shortcut that can do the same thing easily or any other better way in C#?

Comment: You can replace your code with a Linq statement, using a Where and a Select.

Comment: @SveinTerjeGaup can you provide an example on how can I do it with linq?

Comment: Didn't you ask this question a few hours ago?

Comment: You talk about "easy" and "better" but, at least for programming, those are not set in stone and can contradict. Easy could be trying to create a single Linq statement. Is that "easy"? Or maybe longer code but with very clear and easy steps? As for better you can solve this using a temporary hashtable to take the time complexity from O(n*n) to O(n), this will be better if you're having speed problems. In other cases it would be over engineering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that you need a left outer join to get the case of new files and a change of an existing one. This should do it:

```
public IEnumerable<FileConfig> GetNewFiles(IEnumerable<FileConfig> newFiles) =>
    from element1 in newFiles
    join element2 in this.OriginalFiles
        on element1.Name.ToLowerInvariant() equals element2.Name.ToLowerInvariant()
        into g
    where !g.Any() || !element1.MD5Hash.Equals(g.First().MD5Hash, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)
    select new FileConfig
    {
        Name = element1.Name,
        Timestamp = element1.Timestamp,
        MD5Hash = element1.MD5Hash,
    };
```

---

If you made `FileConfig` read-only then you could do this:

```
public IEnumerable<FileConfig> GetNewFiles(IEnumerable<FileConfig> newFiles) =>
    from element1 in newFiles
    join element2 in this.OriginalFiles
        on element1.Name.ToLowerInvariant() equals element2.Name.ToLowerInvariant()
        into g
    where !g.Any() || !element1.MD5Hash.Equals(g.First().MD5Hash, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)
    select element1;
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Yeah I need new files and also files that got modified. Will this work too - `return newFiles.Where(x => !OriginalFiles.Any(a => a.Name == x.Name) || OriginalFiles.Any(a => a.Name == x.Name && a.MD5Hash != x.MD5Hash));`?

Comment: Also if there are no new files + no modified files then I want to return empty `IEnumerable<FileConfig>`. Will that work automatically?

Comment: @cs98 - Your query will work, but it's terribly inefficient. And, yes, my answer will return an empty enumerable if there are no matches.

Comment: aah I see. Can you explain why it is terrible inefficient? It will help me to understand better also is your suggestion efficient?

Comment: @cs98 - For your suggested query you are iterating `OriginalFiles` twice for each and every `newFiles` element. If each list had 1,000 elements then you have the potential to iterate through 2,000,000 elements. My query, by using a join, would only iterate through 2,000 elements. Yours is potentially a thousand times slower.

Answer (score 1):

in your position I would use LinQ. Also we dont know what *FileConfig* is like.

This example returns list of new and changed files.

I have used FileInfo properties. Your FileConfig class can inherit from that with

```
public class FileConfig : FileInfo
```

So you dont miss out for those compareable properties.

```
public class ProcessFile
    {
        public IEnumerable<FileInfo> OriginalFiles { get; set; }


        public IEnumerable<FileInfo> GetNewFiles(IEnumerable<FileInfo> newFiles)
        {
            List<FileInfo> result = new List<FileInfo>();
            result.AddRange(newFiles.Where(x => !OriginalFiles.Any(a => a.FullName == x.FullName) || OriginalFiles.Any(a => a.FullName == x.FullName && a.Length != x.Length)));
            return result;

        }
    }
```

It should be straight forward if you are familiar with LinQ. If not I would suggest some research on it. https://learn.microsoft.com/cs-cz/dotnet/csharp/tutorials/working-with-linq

If you have any question, I will be glad to help you.

LinQ with FileConfig

```
public class ProcessFile
    {
        public IEnumerable<FileConfig> OriginalFiles { get; set; }


        public IEnumerable<FileConfig> GetNewFiles(IEnumerable<FileInfo> newFiles)
        {
            List<FileConfig> result = new List<FileConfig>();
            result.AddRange(newFiles.Where(x => !OriginalFiles.Any(a => a.Name == x.Name) || OriginalFiles.Any(a => a.Name == x.Name && a.MD5Hash != x.MD5Hash)));
            return result;

        }
    }
```

Returning IEnumerable only:

```
   public class ProcessFile
        {
            public IEnumerable<FileConfig> OriginalFiles { get; set; }
    
    
            public IEnumerable<FileConfig> GetNewFiles(IEnumerable<FileInfo> newFiles)
            {
                return newFiles.Where(x => OriginalFiles.Any(a => a.Name != x.Name || (a.Name == x.Name && a.MD5Hash != x.MD5Hash)));
    
            }
        }
```

Comment: thanks for your suggestion. I added FileConfig class. It's a simple class with getters and setters.

Comment: I need to compare `md5Hash` string to figure out what files got modified.  Also if there are new files which are not present in `OriginalFiles` then I need that to be returned as well. `For example:` If `newFiles` object has total `10 files` and `OriginalFiles` has `8 files` so that means there are two new files in it. And then remaining `8` I will compare and see what files are changed by using `md5Hash` string so if 5 files changed out of 8 and there were two new files also so total I will return 7 files as `IEnumerable<FileConfig>` object.

Comment: @cs98 I have added linQ example, so it uses your class. With FileInfo.Legnth you are comparing bit length, so it can be used if the file was modified as well. In new example I have used your md5Hash. Both examples would do exactly the same thing.

Comment: Thanks Tofik. Got it now. So this will return new files + any changed files right? But any files which are same, it won't be returned since md5hash will be same for them correct? Also my return signature is `IEnumerable` but we are returning List? Can we not change this code so that it can return `IEnumerable` only?

Comment: Also what happens if all the files are same + there are no new files present? In that case I want to return empty list or empty `IEnumerable`. Is that possible to do as well?

Comment: @cs98 Added example returning IEnumerable only.

Comment: @cs98 If all files are the same then it would return empty enumerable. You can test it out.

Comment: yeah that makes sense now. ok cool. will test it out.

Comment: @cs98 Dont forget to mark answer, which you ended up using to close the question.